# Text direction in JavaFX alert dialogue

Tags: java, javafx

My whole application is right to left for Persian language. I need to show the alerts in right to left.

How could I change the properties of alert dialogue for this purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to change the `nodeOrientation` on the `dialogPane` of the `Dialog`:

```
Alert alert = ...

alert.getDialogPane().setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 1):

As fabian has suggested [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39032407/2130930), you could do this simply with

`alert.getDialogPane().setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);`

---

But if someone came in searching for some manual way of doing this (though I don't see why anyone would want to do this), then please find the details below-

I have no knowledge of how the languages Right-To-Left work. But you can TextFlow does provide the option to align text right to left. So this might work, but I am not sure!

Also, the following code snippet **does not** edit the text in the alert box itself. But it just adds additional `TextFlow` to the dialog.

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
alert.setTitle("Some title");

Text text = new Text("some right-to-left text here");

TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow();
textFlow.setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);

textFlow.getChildren().addAll(text);

alert.getDialogPane().setContent(textFlow);
alert.show();
```

This is how the dialog box looks, after I added some Google-translated 'Hello World' in Persian. Just did this, so people looking up would directly know if this works or not, rather than having to try it out.

[image: image with persion 'hello world']

The header text does seem to get in the way. So you can remove it by using-

```
alert.setHeaderText(null);
```

EDIT:

Since the buttons are still in English (or Left-Right), here is something you can use, considering you've done the entire application Right-Left, follow same procedure for making the Button texts Right-Left. I wouldn't put time into it, as it is something you already have.

```
ButtonType okBtn; //make sure this is of type ButtonBar.ButtonData.OK_DONE
ButtonType cancelBtn; //make sure this is of type ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION,"",okBtn,cancelBtn);
alert.getDialogPane().setContent(textFlow);

alert.setTitle("Some title");
alert.setHeaderText(null);
Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
```

You can perform the task if OK button is clicked by processing the `result` -
Check if `result.isPresent()` is true and check if `result.get() == okBtn`

The result of this code (ignore the button texts) -

[image]

If this works, then please do let me know. And if it doesn't let me know 'how' its not looking right.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
alert.getDialogPane().getScene().setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

instead of:

```
alert.getDialogPane().setNodeOrientation(NodeOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

to make the title bar direction RTL as well.